# Make button text transparent to reveal animated gradient behind it

Tags: css, background, mask

I have a button that is on top of an element with an animated gradient. What I'd like to happen is for the button's background to be white and the text to be transparent so it reveals the animated gradient behind the button. I'm assuming this is possible somehow, but I am stuck.

Here is what I have so far...

```css
    .gradient {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      text-align: center;
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, #53abdf 0%, #019c92 16%, #a1b524 37%, #a1b524 53%, #ea9c2e 70%, #db4025 85%, #db4025 85%);
      background-size: 200% 100%;
      padding-top: 100px;
      -webkit-animation: moveGradient 40s ease infinite;
    }
    .button {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
      border: 4px solid #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .button:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -webkit-animation: moveGradient 40s ease infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes moveGradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 47%
      }
      50% {
        background-position: 100% 54%
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 0% 47%
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/q69915k3/

Comment: In short you can't. The text appears on top of the button background and can't be used as a hole in it. Hiding the text in any way will just reveal the button background. The closest you can get is to fake it as per @Paulie_D's example but if it's animated it's going to be almost impossible.

Comment: @chris22smith Actually you can but only in browsers that support the `background-clip:text` property. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. That's a good solution with the right fallbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the same linear gradient to the background of the text **within an extra `span`** and then adapt CSS accordingly.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white linear-gradient(135deg, #53abdf 0%, #019c92 16%, #a1b524 37%, #a1b524 53%, #ea9c2e 70%, #db4025 85%, #db4025 85%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: moveGradient 40s ease infinite;
}
.button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.button:hover span {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #53abdf 0%, #019c92 16%, #a1b524 37%, #a1b524 53%, #ea9c2e 70%, #db4025 85%, #db4025 85%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: moveGradient 40s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveGradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 47%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 54%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 47%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <a class="button" href="#"><span>Button</span></a>
</div>
```

**Note though, this isn't perfect because the elements have different sizes so the gradient "size" is actually different so the two don't match precisely.**

Comment: Yeah, I had something like this working yesterday but the problem is I need to have the background of the button white. When I make the background of the button white then you can't see the text.

Comment: Hold on, I think you need a span. Yeah...that works.

Comment: This is great and led me in the right direction. You were right about the background sizes not matching up. So I made the background size on the button like 1900% wide and it matches up pretty good. The other issue is that since the animation was on the hover the animation restarted with each separate hover. So I moved the animation property to the span without hover to keep the two animations in sync. Its probably not 100% perfect but its very, very close. The % widths work out pretty well for responsive too!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the text in a element and make it `opacity: 0;` when the button is hovered

HTML:

```
<div class="gradient">
   <a class="button" href="#"><span class="hide">button</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button:hover .hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```